# if elif turn into more convenient approach

Tags: python

Is there any way to make those if statements to more cleaner approach by means to some kind of switch statement?

```
def col_type_generator(self, val):
        if "int" or "tinyint" in val:
            return " A"
        elif "longtext" or "mediumtext" or "text" or "tinytext" or "json" in val:
            return " B"
        elif "varchar" in val:
            return " C"
        elif "bit" in val:
            return " D"
        elif "datetime" in val:
            return " E"
        else:
            return "UNKNOWN COLUMN TYPE"
```

Comment: The first two `if`s don't work the way you expect them to. The first `if` will always be true.

Comment: The posted function body is equivalent to `return "A"`, since `bool("int")` is `True`.  To do what you want, change it to `if "int" in val or "tinyint" in val:`, and similarly for the `elif` that follows.  Hint:  If you're looking for ways to improve your code, a good place to start is to get it to actually work as intended.

Comment: You can make a list of tuples `(<type>, <return value>)`, iterate over it and return the value if the type is found.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Or a dict, then it will even be O(1)

Comment: Remember that incoming value may contain the type within the text therefore LIKE has to be used. For example `val` can be `aintb` then appropriate case like `"int"` has to be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make those if statements to more cleaner approach by means to some kind of switch statement?

Python's "some kind of switch statement" is called [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=case#grammar-token-python-grammar-match_stmt) so that's one option:

```py
def col_type_generator(self, val):
    match val:
        case "int" | "tinyint":
            return " A"
        case "longtext" | "mediumtext" | "text" | "tinytext" | "json":
            return " B"
        case "varchar":
            return " C"
        case "bit":
            return " D"
        case "datetime":
            return " E"
        case _:
            return "UNKNOWN COLUMN TYPE"
```

Although the more usual (and compatible as `match` is quite recent) way to handle such a *mapping* of input values to output values would be to use a *mapping*, such as a dict:

```py
_COL_TYPE_MAPPING = {
    "int": " A",
    "tinyint": " A",
    "longtext": " B",
    "mediumtext": " B",
    "text": " B",
    "tinytext": " B",
    "json": " B",
    "varchar": " C",
    "bit": " D",
    "datetime": " E",
}

def col_type_generator(self, val):
    return _COL_TYPE_MAPPING.get(val, "UNKNOWN COLUMN TYPE")
```

Comment: Note that it has to be LIKE ... means incomming val can have int(11) then it should go to the "int" case

Comment: That can be resolved by parsing / splitting the input to extract only the useful type bit where applicable. Split on `(` and dispatch on the first element for instance. Or match on the `\w+` regex. Or full blown parsing of the typespec if you need to dispatch on other bits.